# Notation in definition of a quantity involving uncertainty and posterior probability

Tags: probability, bayesian, posterior, notation, active-learning

As a probs & stats noob, I'm still getting confused by notation. I would appreciate if someone could elaborate a bit on what's going on here, on p12 of Settles' Active Learning survey (2012).

He writes:

> For problems with three or more class labels, a more general uncertainty sampling-variant might query the instance whose prediction is *least confident*: $$x^*_{LC} = \mathrm{argmax}_x 1-P_{\theta}(\hat{y}|x),$$
>   where $\hat{y} = \mathrm{argmax}_y P_{\theta}(y|x)$, or the class label with the highest posterior probability under the model $\theta$. One way to interpret  this uncertainty measure is the expected 0/1 loss, i.e. the  model's belief that it will mislabel $x$.

Could someone please explain exactly what probabilities those two $P_{\theta}(\cdot)$ are referring to? How to think about "posterior" in this context, and why can this be interpreted as a belief of mislabeling $x$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$P_{\theta}(\hat{y}|x)$ is a probability of observing $y$ given the information $x$ as judged by the model $\theta$. If model $\theta$ "thinks" that given $x$ the most likely value you should predict is $y$ (with probability $p$), then if you decide to choose other label instead, the model would argue, that according to it's best knowledge you are wrong with probability $1-p$. Saying it differently, if according to $\theta$, probability that for the label $y$ is $p$, then you can think of this probability as of a measure of how much $\theta$ *believes* that the label you should assign is $p$.

Comment: Is that supposed to be $P_{\theta}(\hat{y}|x)$ or $P_{\theta}(y|x)$? Ok, so one point of my confusion was thinking $x,y$ were objects of the same type, but I see now I should think about $x,y$ respectively as elements in the domain and codomain of a random variable? It's beginning to make more sense, but then what does it mean in the posterior probably "the information $x$"? That just means we restrict attention to the element $x$ in the probability space?